# Куда помещать файл .htaccess в WAMP?

Tags: php, javascript, .htaccess

Куда помещать файл .htaccess в WAMP?
В папку www или в папку сайта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Упрощенный ответ:**
.htaccess файл сервер ищет при каждом запросе в каждой папке начиная с DocumentRoot данного сайта, обычно с корневой папки сайта, это там же где index.php, index.html. Откуда index отображается, рядом и положите.

**Полный ответ:**
В файле конфигурации apache (начиная с 2.4 обязательно) задаются правила обработки .htaccess файлов. За это отвечает инструкция AllowOverride All
в соответствующей секции.

Если инструкция включена, то сервер при каждом запросе к нему будет искать файлы .htaccess, причем не только в текущей, но все родительские папки. Он ищет его везде, но от DocumentRoot или другого заданного пути.

В большинстве платформ для разработки AllowOverride All включена для всего, а так как .htaccess действует в любой папке, то нужно положить там где он нужен.
Если не в корне сайта, а в внутри, то проверяем дополнительно в нем от какого пути он отталкивается при rewrite rule.

При развертывании на сервере на высоко нагруженных проектах снижение нагрузки достигается в том числе и отключением всех файлов .htaccess с переносом информации в конфигурационный файл, который читается один раз.